# Why does locationManager delegate not call when app on app store

Tags: ios, swift, location

My app completely works with

```
@objc func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
```

And permissions for WhenInUse are added correctly in Info.plist, are requested correctly, etc.

However, after just releasing the app to the store, locationManager does no longer get called. When it does get called (on the developer version of app), I focus the map on a small region of current location. However, it never gets to this on the commercial version, but you can see the blue dot and a map of the world.

(Yes, the alert asking for permission did come up, and I did press okay)

How do I work out what is preventing it to be called on a live version of app? Or what the actual difference is between the live and developer app when It comes to location?

**UPDATE: Please note all works perfectly when I run it locally on my device from XCode, or even re open the local version. It doesn't work when I try the version from the app store.**

Comment: Is location enabled in privacy preferences settings in iOS ? Are you calling startingUpdateLocations on app startup ?

Comment: Yes absolutely - hence why it works on locally run app.